# ifelse() returns logical(0) when trying to change values

Tags: r

right now I am trying to omit specific trials from my data frame. If peoples response times to a certain scenario they saw is too long or too short, I want to exclude these trials from my analysis.
I already identified the observations, and now I want to replace them with `NA`s. For this, I wanted to use an `ifelse()`- Statement. If their response time `log_TIME` is above or below a certain threshold (above 5.3 or below 2.01), then I want to replace their answers to those scenarios in the variable `answer` coded with `0` and `1`, to be `NA`.
My data looks something like this:

```
logTIME001    answer001

2.944439      1
3.912023      1
3.583519      0
1.098612      1
3.850148      0
5.700444      1
```

This is the code I tried:

```
ifelse(df$logTIME001 > 5.310, df$answer001 == "NA")
ifelse(df$logTIME001 < 2.01, df$answer001 == "NA")
```

But if I do this, it returns `logical(0)` and all of the values in `answer001` turn to `NA`s. How can I fix this? Is this even the correct code or do I have to use a different one? Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote out a solution for you with the standard iris dataframe. You should be able to apply it to your problem.

```
library(datasets)
head(iris)
iris$Species[iris$Sepal.Length<4.5 | iris$Sepal.Length>5.5] <- NA
```

iris$Species defines which column you want to replace with NA

iris$Sepal.Length defines which column you want to check for a certain condition

| is the logical OR connector for the two conditions; if either is true it overwrites the row entry of the species column with NA

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here. `ifelse` has three arguments `ifelse(test, yes, no)` (see `?ifelse`). Then we code `NA`s without quotation marks.

```
ifelse(df$logTIME001 > 5.310, NA, df$answer001)
# [1]  1  1  0  1  0 NA
ifelse(df$logTIME001 < 2.01, NA, df$answer001)
# [1]  1  1  0 NA  0  1
```

Probably better, though, to use `within` here:

```
df <- within(df, {
  answer001[logTIME001 > 5.310 | logTIME001 < 2.01] <- NA
})
df
#   logTIME001 answer001
# 1   2.944439         1
# 2   3.912023         1
# 3   3.583519         0
# 4   1.098612        NA
# 5   3.850148         0
# 6   5.700444        NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(logTIME001 = c(2.944439, 3.912023, 3.583519, 1.098612, 
3.850148, 5.700444), answer001 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```